# Two Error Handlers in one procedure to check if two workbooks are open?

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I have two error handlers to look for if two separate workbooks are open?

```vb
Sub ErrHandler()
    wbsource_name=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
    wbdest_name=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value
    On Error GoTo Here
    Set wb_source=Workbooks(wbsource_name)
Here:
    MsgBox "Open main file"
    Exit Sub

   'I want here to stop first err handler
   'The next file to be opened(or looked if is open)
   'So if first file is open, but second not. It again gives the first error handler message

    On Error GoTo 0
    On Error GoTo Here2
    Set wb_destination=Workbooks(wbdest_name)
Here2:
    MsgBox "Open UPO file"
```

I tried `On error GoTo 0` to neutralize the first error handler.
I also tried `On error Resume Next`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to push out a potentially error-generating action into a separate method (particularly that action is repeated in the main code).

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim wbSrc As Workbook, wbDest As Workbook, wbsource_name As String, wbdest_name As String

    wbsource_name = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
    wbdest_name = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value
    
    Set wbSrc = GetOpenWorkbook(wbsource_name, "Workbook '" & wbsource_name & "' must be open")
    If wbSrc Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Set wbDest = GetOpenWorkbook(wbdest_name, "Workbook '" & wbdest_name & "' must be open")
    If wbDest Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
      
End Sub

'Return an open workbook given its name, or Nothing if not found
'  Optional message `msgMissing` to show if not found
Function GetOpenWorkbook(wbName As String, Optional msgMissing As String = "") As Workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetOpenWorkbook = Workbooks(wbName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If GetOpenWorkbook Is Nothing And Len(msgMissing) > 0 Then 
        MsgBox msgMissing
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: @Tim Williams, I liked the simplicity of your code. However, I have managed by changing GoTo 0 to GoTo -1. And it works fine. But I want to understand and try your approach also. Could you help me to undertand it? GetOpenWorkbook will it open workbooks if my variables only include the workbook names? I do not use the pathway of workbook.

Comment: @VBasic2008 - thanks I have fixed those two items

Comment: @user16316847 - no it cannot open the workbook if it's not already open, unless there's a fixed location where it would "know" the workbook could be opened from.  Your code as posted only has the file names.

Answer (score 0):

### Create Workbook References

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TestOpenWorkbooks()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim swbName As String: swbName = ws.Range("A1").Value
    Dim dwbName As String: dwbName = ws.Range("B1").Value
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks(swbName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If swb Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Open main file."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks(dwbName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If dwb Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Open UPO file."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    MsgBox "Files open. Ready to continue."

End Sub

Sub TestOpenWorkbooksImproved()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim swbName As String: swbName = ws.Range("A1").Value
    Dim dwbName As String: dwbName = ws.Range("B1").Value
    
    Dim wbPath As String: wbPath = "C:\Test\"
    
    ' This will work either way: open or not open.
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(wbPath & swbName)
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks.Open(wbPath & dwbName)

    MsgBox "Files open. Ready to continue."

End Sub
```

### EDIT

```
Sub TestOpenWorkbooksFunction()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim swbName As String: swbName = ws.Range("A1").Value
    Dim dwbName As String: dwbName = ws.Range("B1").Value
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = RefWorkbook(swbName)
    If swb Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Open main file."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = RefWorkbook(dwbName)
    If dwb Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Open UPO file."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    MsgBox "Files open. Ready to continue."

End Sub

Function RefWorkbook( _
    ByVal WorkbookName As String) _
As Workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set RefWorkbook = Workbooks(WorkbookName)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Sub RefWorkbookTEST()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = RefWorkbook("?")
    If wb Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Nope"
    Else
        Debug.Print wb.Name
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Code is too long and hard to understand for me, I managed to bring the error of the second workbook with changing On Error Got To 0 to On Error GoTo -1. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I would suggest you have another crack at it since it illustrates crucial error handling in VBA. Officially, there is no `On Error GoTo -1` in the [VBA On Error Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement). Also, you might learn a lot from the Chip Pearson's [Error Handling in VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm) page.

Comment: wow! Great Thanks for resource! I will certainly look at it. Also, you both have used UDFunctions in your procedures...I nver use udf but I know how to write them. Is there any necessity or you know exactly where to go UDF functions. If you could give some res.s on where to use UDF I will be grateful. thanks a lot!)

Comment: "UDF" is usually reserved for VBA functions intended to be called from a range on a worksheet.  Neither answer here uses a UDF - just a regular VBA Function (the main difference between a Sub and a Function is just that a Function returns a value and a Sub does not).  So if you want to *get* something you'd call a Function: if you want to *do* something you'd call a Sub.